# How can I retrieve the name of the categories to which a post belongs

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, blogs

I'm learning Laravel by developing a small blog in order to learn the framework and what it has to offer. The problem I'm now facing is that "How can I retrive the name of the categories to which the post originally belong to"

My relationship between posts and categories is many to many.
I have three Tables

```
Post
Category
CategoryPost
```

My Post Model

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\category');
    }
```

My Categories Model

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
```

Other than that I have not made any model of the pivot table.
Do I need to make it?

The records present in my pivot table are as follows:

```
    id  category_id  post_id  
------  -----------  ---------
     6            1         16
     7            2         16
     8            3         16
     9            1         17
    10            3         17
    11            1         18
    12            2         18
```

I want to display the name of the current category to which a post belongs to originally so that the user can add or remove the categories in the edit page.

These are my migrations:

Post Table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->Integer('status_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->text('media');
            $table->string('tags');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Category Table:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

CategoryPost Table:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide what you tried in your controller?

Comment: public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        $post=Post::find($post->id);
        $categories=Category::all();
        return view('admin.pages.post.edit',compact('post','categories'));
    }

Comment: This is what i have tried so far in the edit method of the post controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit migration:

#### CategoryPost Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
            $table->Integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->Integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function edit(Post $post) {
 $post=Post::with('categories')->find($post->id);
 $categories=Category::all(); 

 return view('admin.pages.post.edit',compact('post','categories')); }
```

And in your blade you are be able to do something like this:

```
@foreach($post->categories as $category)
    {{ $category->name }}
@endforeach
```

This should works, but if you have errors provide it here.

Comment: Tried this now but to my surprise, it neither is showing any error nor is displaying anything. Even dd isn't showing anything

Comment: When you `dd($post)` in your controller do you get results in relations? Or what you get when `dd($post->categories)`?

Comment: I'm only getting the data that is present in the Post table. it isn't showing any relation data

Comment: When i dd($post) i get the data that the post has in the database. When i do dd($post->categories) it displays Collection {#309 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: Ok. This is because you somewhere missed `foreign_key`. Can you update your question with migrations for your `CategoryPost` table. Because your pivot table need foreign keys from `Category` and `Post` maybe is there problem.

Comment: yeah your migrations wasn't good. Now try like this. Maybe you will get new errors. I need to go now, I will be here in 2 hours. So if you can't solve on your own wait for me. Good luck! :)

Comment: No man got an error           Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'category_id' and referenced colu
mn 'id' in foreign key constraint 'category_post_category_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `category_post` add cons
traint `category_post_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`))

Comment: You got that when run migration or?

Comment: yup when i did php artisan migrate i got this error

Comment: is your `category_post` migration after `posts` and `categoies` ?

Comment: yup this was the last migration that i created and migrated.

Comment: Ok you probably need `bigInteger` I will update my answer. Updated @OvaisTariq

Comment: Yes thee was something wrong in the migration fixed that now i'm able to migrate rest ill try and update you